# How to write Client side event code in aspx.code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Tomorrow i wrote code to show popup panel in via `button client side event handler` and via Event handler of this same button i am applying few complex logic. Well all is working fine. But one thing that i am unable to manage is to show 3rd party popup-panel `after implementation of code i am writing in button event handler` .

**Problem:** Panel show before implementation of a code. Now i want to call that java-script code after button event-handler in aspx.code. How to do that? 
My code is:

```
     <dx:ASPxButton ID="editbelow" runat="server"  Text="Edit" AutoPostBack="False" Width="70px" OnClick="editbelow_Click">
        <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e)
        {
          ASPxPopupControl1.Show(); 
        }" />
    </dx:ASPxButton>


    protected void editbelow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (k.lookid == abc.lookid)
       {
             ASPxHtmlEditor1.Html = "This is "+ k.lookname;
             //HERE I WANT TO WRITE THAT CLIENT SIDE HANDLER.HOW TO DO THAT?
             break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure you can handle client side event is aspx because as far as i know aspx is server side code. I would use Javascript to handle client side events, and then call aspx to run the event code

Comment: Have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx ?